# Remove Multiple Time Series from Table in Power Query Editor

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a data set which I want to attribute some new values but since **the table has multiple identical time series per for one unit** I end up with too many values. unfortunately removing duplicates does not work, since the time series repeat for every unit.

My Question is: How could I remove the excess data.

The Data set looks something like this rn:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6PWc.png)

And this would be my optimal outcome:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLkRP.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Removing duplicates will absolutely work.  Just click select **BOTH** columns then right click and remove duplicates.